# .NET 8 with HTTP/2 and HTTP/1 grpc and rest api simultaneously

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, grpc, .net-8.0

I'm trying create an ASP.NET Core 8 API and AOT Native, but I need this API to have a REST endpoint (http1) and a GRPC endpoint (http2) simultaneously, what options do I have to configure this?

I tried using kestrel endpoints in `appsettings.json`:

```
"Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://localhost:5000",
        "Protocols": "Http2"
      },
      "Https": {
        "Url": "https://localhost:5001",
        "Protocols": "Http2"
      }
    }
},
```

And:

```
"Kestrel": {
    "EndpointDefaults": {
      "Protocols": "Http1AndHttp2"
    }
},
```

But I always get different errors where the API call isn't even made correctly.

I'm completely lost as I have 0 experience with .NET, any idea what to do?

This is my `launchSettings.json`:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:17251",
      "sslPort": 44325
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "https": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: in the appsettings file use the code:`"Kestrel": {
       "Endpoints": {
         "Http1": {
           "Url": "http://localhost:5000",
           "Protocols": "Http1"
         },
         "Http2": {
           "Url": "http://localhost:5001",
           "Protocols": "Http2"
         }
       }
     }` The `launchSettings.json` should match the ports and protocols you configured in `appsettings.json`.Verify that the `applicationUrl` in `launchSettings.json` aligns with your `appsettings.json` configuration.